# Optimizing an expression by selecting 2 random values

Tags: c++

I have an expression

```
abs(z - x*a + y*b)
```

where z, a and b are given for example

If z=2, a=1, b=2; then our equation will look like `abs(2-x*1+y*2)`. So we have to select x and y values in such a way that the expression value is minimized

I have tried a brute force approach i.e using two loops from -z to z and trying all possible values mentioned below

```
int bestval(int a,int b,int m)
{
    int ans=INT_MAX;
    for(int i=-m;i<=m;i++)
    {
        for(int j=-m;j<=m;j++)
        {
        ans=min(ans,abs(m-a*i+b*j));
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Is there any optimized approach? I was thinking of binary seach but I don't know how I gonna apply it

Comment: after derivating  wrt to i of eqn pow(m-a*i+b*j),2) am ending up with -2a*(m-a*i+b*j)=0 which implies m=a*i-b*j  and -2b*(m-a*i+b*j) when derivating wrtj

Comment: The minimum of `abs(z - x*a + y*b)` will be where `y*b - x*a = z` or where `y = (a/b)x + z/b` (which is the equation for a Line `y = mx + b_yint`) where *slope* `m = a/b` and *y-intercept* `b_yint = z/b`. So for any value `x` you have the corresponding value of `y` on the line that satisfies the line equation resulting in the minimum of `abs(z - x*a + y*b)`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thats really quality information so you mean instead of using 2 loops i can reduce this in one loop? but ultimately x and y values should have known to me to satisfy that equation how can i do that ??

Comment: Yes. Since you know that every point on the line will satisfy making `abs(z - x*a + y*b)` minimum you only need to loop over one variable to find the other. Think about it. All you are doing is saying you have a minimum at `abs(0)`. So any values of `x` and `y` that result with something other than zero are not a minimum. By approaching it in this manner and using the relationship that all points that make a minimum lie on a line, you effectively eliminate an independent variable making one dependent on the other.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin what will be the range for looping over that one variablye as earlier i was taking it from -z to +z will it be the same now too??

Comment: You choose your range, because you are correct, it doesn't matter what you choose, looking around `-10` for `x` to positive `10` should be fine. You can always find your *x-intercept* and choose the range around it  and you have the *y-intercept* so you can use a range around there as well (or just make sure it is covered by your choice of range in `x`.Now you are in a position to loop and find the minimum values for both `x` and `y` with a short iteration over a small range.

Comment: With your `a, b, z` values of `1, 2, 2` if you loop `-10 to 10` while all points will provide the same `abs(0)` the minimum points `(x, y)` will be around `(0, 1)` if looking to minimize the numeric value of the points for the minimum, or at `(2, 2)` if looking to minimize the difference between the point values at the min. So it is up to you to figure out what points you want to take from that line, but understand, ALL points on that line will provide the same `abs(0)` minimum.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it via calculus, Compute derivate of aforementioned equation, find critical points, plug in critical points in equations and voila, you get your solution. See [this link](https://mathinsight.org/minimization_maximization_refresher) for example. Moreover, since there are two variables you'd have to use [chain rule](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/chain/chain.html). Use this cheat sheet

1. Derivative of `|x|` wrt `x` is `x/|x|`
2. Derivative of `A*x^n` wrt `x` is `A * n * (x ^(n-1))` (`A` is a constant)

Comment: but there are 2 unknown variables

Comment: with what respect i should derivate the expression

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous algorithms for optimisation.

I suggest that you start with [Nelder-Mead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method). It's not necessarily the fastest but it is generally robust and does not require derivatives.